# Base<T1, T2> where T1:class where T2:class 'The type mus be a reference...'

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6

I'm not sure where I'm messing this up. Been looking for an answer but none solves my actual problem.

My code is as follows:

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public abstract class CRUDBaseEntity<TDTO, TEntity>
        where TDTO : class
        where TEntity : class
    {
        public virtual TDTO GetSingle(Expression<Func<TDTO, bool>> where)
        {
            TDTO item = null;
            using (var context = new MyEntities())
            {
                Func<TDTO, bool> delegated = where.Compile();
                Func<TEntity, bool> destWere = d => delegated(MapDTOFromEntity(d));
                IQueryable<TEntity> dbQuery = context.Set<TEntity>();

                var fetch = dbQuery
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefault(destWere); 
                if (fetch == null) return null;
                item = MapDTOFromEntity(fetch);
            }
            return item;
        }        
    }

    public class Specific : CRUDBaseEntity<DTO.DTOSpecific, DataAccess.SpecificEntity>
    {

    }
}

namespace Client
{
    public class ClientClass
    {
        public void Caller()
        {
            var fetch = new BusinessLogic.Specific().GetSingle(f => f.SomeProperty.Equals("someValue"));
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I'm getting:

> "The type '`DataAccess.SpecificEntity`' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter '`TEntity`' in the generic type or method '`BusinessLogic.CRUDBaseEntity<TDTO,TEntity>`'

Evidently, there's no issue with the DTO as it is referenced at the client.
Notice that BusinessLogic, DataAccess and Client are 3 diferent projects of the same solution.

EDIT:
SpecificEntity is an EntityFramework autogenerated class representing an Entity from my database. Quite plain:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SpecificEntity
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public SpecificEntity()
        {
            this.SpecificEntityPriceList = new HashSet<SpecificEntityPriceList>();
        }

        public string SpecificEntityId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual SpecificEntityCategory SpecificEntityCategory { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SpecificEntityPriceList> SpecificEntityPriceList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `DataAccess.SpecificEntity` a class?

Comment: The code does not compile. Please show the code of `DataAccess.SpecificEntity`.

Comment: You could read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for reference on Constraints for Type parameters.

Comment: @GillBates, DataAccess.SpecificEnitty is an Entity of my Entity Framework data model.

Comment: Yes, so make it a class if it isn't already.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, it does not. DataAccess.SpecificEnitty is an Entity of my Entity Framework data model. You, however, can replicate this code on whichever application you have using Entity Framework and a matching DTO. Thanks

Comment: @GillBates it is a class. I've edited the original question

Comment: Rather than adding pieces of code piecemeal to your question, please try to create an [mcve]. We can't compile your code. If I attempt to substitute in "obvious" empty implementations, the code you *have* shown doesn't generate the error your showing. So you need to put more work into creating an example that stands by itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for your comments. Take into account that BusinessLogic, DataAccess and Client are 3 different project on the same solution.